# How to distribute n distinct balls into r numbered boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing this assignment and thinking the answer should be S(n,r) multiply by r!
that is partition the balls into r cells. but here order matters. so need to multiply r! ways of ordering the boxes.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your answer is correct, assuming that each box is required to get at least one ball, and your reasoning is correct as well. By the way, this is equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^{r-k}\binom{r}kk^n\;,$$ by an inclusion-exclusion argument counting the surjections from $[n]$ to $[r]$. If there is no requirement that each box get at least one ball, then the answer is much simpler: see **The Emperor of Ice Cream**’s answer.

Comment: why must each box get at least one ball?

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream: We don’t know whether that’s a hypothesis or not. The OP didn’t mention it, but the argument offered is clearly based on that assumption. We’ll have to wait and see whether the question as stated or the argument actually reflects the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

There should be $r^n$ different ways to do so since for each marble there are $r$ choices. We must take this decision $n$ times.+

The [twelvefold way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) contains the answers to many of these counting problems.